# Recent data on top browsers' memory use?

Tags: browser, memory

Does anyone know of any decent tests done within the last year which measured how memory hungry the main browsers are?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an [article](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/firefox-chrome-opera,2558-4.html) about memory usage comparison of popular browsers dated March 4, 2010.

From article:

[image]

Another [article](http://cybernetnews.com/browser-comparison-internet-explorer-firefox-chrome-safari-opera/), dated July 9, 2009, gives memory usage statistics in a table:

[image]

The best browser for each test is highlighted in green, and the worst is highlighted in red.

Comment: +1, I use Chrome, really like the translation features, but its such a mem hog, luckily I have 6GB's of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

[GHacks](http://www.ghacks.net/2016/01/03/32-bit-vs-64-bit-browsers-which-version-has-the-edge/) provides 2016's data on 32/64-bit browsers memory consumption:

[image: Firefox vs Chrome vs Edge vs Pale Moon vs Vivaldi RAM usage]

The winner after opening 10 tabs is [Pale Moon](https://www.palemoon.org/) 32-bit.